# Lubuntu 18.04 asks me for encryption key on each reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, disk-encryption

On Ubuntu 16.04, I used to encrypt the filesystem but it was automatically decrypted when I input the password. Now I've installed Lubuntu 18.04 and it asks me for the encryption key each time before the normal login prompt.

How do I make it behave as 16.04 did?

Comment: With a full drive encryption it is supposed to *always* ask the encryption password before the user's login password.

Comment: If so then something is wrong with with your 16.04, not now with 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu 18.04 installer no longer offers the possibility to encrypt the `home` folder only, which is what I did in Ubuntu 16.04 (thus being able to only input the user password). Full disk encryption requires the encryption key on startup.

[This question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04) may be used as a reference for how to encrypt `home` only in Ubuntu 18.04.